# Xamarin DialogViewController not disposed when Root is set

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm having a weird problem. I'm using Subclasses of DialogViewController for a multi-page interview. Each page presents a number of fields that can be edited, and hitting save in the upper right pushes the next page onto the NavigationController. It seemed to be working fine, but it became apparent that backing out and repeating the interview leaks memory. I created a simple test case that properly cleans up the button event for the navigation item. In this example, Dispose is called when the second controller is popped, but only if I don't set Root to something other than null (i.e. this works as expected if I comment the Root = ... line). Here's the code. Please tell me I'm missing something stupid.

```
public class TestViewController : DialogViewController { int mPage;

public TestViewController (int page) : base (null, true)
{
    mPage = page;

    Root = new RootElement ("Testing") {
        new Section () {
            new StringElement ("Page: " + mPage)
        }
    };
}

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play);
}

public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

    NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem.Clicked += OnClicked;
}

public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);

    NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem.Clicked -= OnClicked;
}

private void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationController.PushViewController(new TestViewController(mPage + 1), true);
}

protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose (disposing);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete self contained example of what you are doing,  including the nav controller part?

Comment: Can you try what happens if you move Root creation to ViewDidAppear and then dispose it on ViewDidDisappear? I suspect that RootElement is keeping its native objects alive and thus preventing GC from collecting the view controller.

Comment: The navigation controller is set as the root viewcontroller, like: window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(new TestViewController(1));

Comment: With a little more testing, I was able to get them to dispose by putting int navLength = NavigationController.ViewControllers.Length; in ViewWillAppear (I think anything that accesses the ViewControllers property will do the same).  Without that, that aren't popped until a new controller is pushed back on.  Similarly, if I want to kill the whole navigation stack (from a leftbarbuttonitem click) I had to clear the stack with NavigationController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {}; to get it to dispose.  I guess this works, but it seems pretty terrible.  I thought this was fixed in 3.0.

Comment: Try enabling the **New RefCount extensions** in your project options (new, well **much** enhanced in 7.2.1+ but not yet the default).

Comment: Yep, I have that turned on.  It didn't seem to have an effect.